# Whitenoiseを使用するDajngoにおいて、static タグがサーバーエラーを発生させる問題について

Tags: python, python3, django, heroku

Djangoの設定で`DEBUG = False`をセットした時に、テンプレートファイル内の`static`タグがServerError(500)を発生させてしまいます。
`DEBUG = True`の時には発生しません。また、下記の記述に変更しても問題なく動作します（組み込みの`/admin`が動かないのですが…）

```
<!-- Error -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'bootstrap-4/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
<!-- Not error -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/bootstrap-4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

`manage.py runserver`では問題は発生しないので、`whitenoise`や`gunicorn`の設定が原因ではないかなと思ってます。

主に下記の構成で動かしているのですが、

- Python 3.7.0
- Django 2.1.3
- whitenoise 4.1
- gunicorn 19.9.0

解決策を教えてください。

#### requirements.txt

```
dj-database-url==0.5.0
Django==2.1.3
django-bootstrap4==0.0.7
django-cleanup==2.1.0
django-debug-toolbar==1.10.1
django-extended-choices==1.3
django-extensions==2.1.3
django-heroku==0.3.1
flake8==3.6.0
future==0.17.1
gunicorn==19.9.0
mccabe==0.6.1
Pillow==5.3.0
psycopg2==2.7.5
pycodestyle==2.4.0
pyflakes==2.0.0
pytz==2018.7
six==1.11.0
sqlparse==0.2.4
whitenoise==4.1
```

#### staticfiles in settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

#### heroku run settings

```
import django_heroku
from .settings import *

DEBUG = False
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

#### Directory

```
- project_root
  - config
    - settings.py
    - heroku_settings.py
  - static
    - common_static_files
```

#### Error message

```
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 419, in stored_name
raise ValueError("Missing staticfiles manifest entry for '%s'" % clean_name)
ValueError: Missing staticfiles manifest entry for 'bootstrap-4/css/bootstrap.min.css'
```

Comment: [このページのAnswer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50658241/django-doesnt-load-static-files-valueerrormissing-staticfiles-manifest-entry)で解決しませんかね？

Comment: 解決しませんでした。`django_heroku` でwhitenoise周りの設定されるのは確認しています。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決

`STATICFILES_STORAGE` に指定するモジュールにバグがあるのか、`STATICFILES_STORAGE` の設定を削除(`del`)することで動作することを確認しました。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26829435/collectstatic-command-fails-when-whitenoise-is-enabled/32347324#32347324